# Debug irrelevant Wordpress search results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search

On Wordpress, I keep getting irrelevant search results.

- Some search strings that do not exist on the DB yield All Posts as results.
- Some search strings that DO exist, works great.

What could be the cause of that behavior? I've uninstalled all related plugins. Is there a way to debug the search?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the default theme? It could be something your theme does

Comment: What in the theme can cause this? Search results template?

Comment: That sounds like a good place to start looking :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip, Greg :)

For some reason I thought  in the search template would be a good idea. Removed this line, everything is right.